# When using Symfony2.1 forms, at what point should I bind custom data (an object) based on form values to my form's object?

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

Given the following scenario, where should I put logic to bind Department to Review:

Entities:

- Dealership (has many departments)
- Department (has one type)
- DepartmentType
- Review (has one dealership and one department)

On my ReviewForm I need the user to be able to select a Dealership and a DepartmentType, and then in some form of callback or pre/post bind, work out from them which Department to bind to the Review.

I also need this to happen prior to validation so that I can validate that the Department is child of the Dealership.

Note: Review relates to both Dealership and Department when it *could* just relate to Department to ease traversal and other logic I have going on.

---

There are two approaches I've tried so far but reached deadends / confusion.

- DataTransformer on the DepartmentType on the form, not sure I understand this properly, my transform / reverseTransform methods were getting passed in the Review object, not the field object.
- PRE_BIND, happens before validation but I only have raw data to work with, no objects
- POST_BIND, happens after validation :(

For the final step of validation of the relationship I have a relatively simple validator that should do the job, but I'm not sure at what point I am meant to bind data to the object like this. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you post your data transformer / relevant type classes?  I'll give it a stab.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, I've solved this now with help from @benlumley, I've updated his answer to feature full code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a standard (ie: non-Doctrine) choice type containing a choice to represent each DepartmentType.

Then use a DataTransformer to turn the selected option into the relevant type, and vice versa.

---

Your custom FormType should end up looking something like this:

```
class Department extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new DepartmentToTypeTransformer($this->em);
        $builder->addViewTransformer($transformer, true);

        $builder->getParent()->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_BIND, function($event) use ($transformer) {
            $data = (object) $event->getData();
            $transformer->setDealership($data->dealership);
        });
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'department';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $choices = array();

        foreach ($this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:DepartmentType')->findAll() as $type) {
            $choices[$type->getId()] = (string) $type;
        }

        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => $choices,
            'expanded' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

Note the passing of the Dealership into the DataTransformer for use in the transformation.

---

And DataTransformer something like this:

```
class DepartmentToTypeTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $em;
    private $dealership;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function transform($department)
    {
        if (null === $department) {
            return $department;
        }

        return $department->getType()->getId();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($type)
    {
        if (null === $type) {
            return $type;
        }

        return $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Department')->findOneBy(array(
            'dealership' => $this->getDealership(),
            'type' => $type
        ));
    }

    public function getDealership() {
        return $this->dealership;
    }

    public function setDealership($dealership) {
        $this->dealership = $dealership;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

Your confusion regarding what is being passed to your transformer is most likely caused by the transformer you're binding being appended to pre-existing behaviour, try adding `true` as the second parameter to addViewTransformer:

```
    $transformer = new DepartmentToTypeTransformer($this->em);
    $builder->addViewTransformer($transformer, true);
```

From [the docs](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html):

```
FormBuilder::addViewTransformer(
    DataTransformerInterface $viewTransformer,
    Boolean $forcePrepend = false
)

Appends / prepends a transformer to the view transformer chain.
```

Answer (score 2):

As validation is also done in a POST_BIND listener, you could simply add your POST_BIND listener with a higher priority than the validation listener (i.e. anything > 0).

If you're writing a listener:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, $myListener, 10);
```

and if you're writing a subscriber:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        FormEvents::POST_BIND => array('postBind', 10),
    );
}

public function postBind(FormEvent $event)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Bernhard, I did end up using a PRE_BIND listener, but only to pass the Dealership into the DataTransformer for the transformation.